# Always Blocks with multiple sensitivities

Tags: verilog

I am trying to implement an FSM that reacts to either one of two buttons being pressed. Let's call these buttons A and B. What I want is something like:

```
always@(posedge A or posedge B) begin
    if(A) begin **do one thing**
      end else if (B) begin **do another**
    end
end
```

The situation I am scared of is the case when, for example, the user is holding down button A and then presses B. The if statement would detect that A is high, when the actual sensitive parameter I want a reaction to is B. How can I do this in Verilog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to register the values of A and B, and compare them to their current values. This requires a system clock of some sort, but you're likely already using one for your FSM.

As an example:

```
input A, B;
input clk;
reg A_prev, B_prev;

always @(posedge clk)
begin
    A_prev <= A;
    B_prev <= B;
end

always @(*)
begin
    if (A && !A_prev) **do whatever**
    else if (B && !B_prev) **do whatever**
end
```

Since A and B are registered, the second `always` block will detect if A (or B) was low on the previous clock cycle and is now high.

Comment: This will produce a warning in iverilog: "warning: @* found no sensitivities so it will never trigger."

Answer (score 4):

One way or another, you need to keep track of the state of "A has been depressed and has not yet been released," etc.  You can either track that state externally to your state machine, as in @wilcroft's answer, or as part of your state machine.  To handle this as part of the state machine you would need to change the sensitivity list to respond to either presses or releases (i.e. not just posedge), and include state information for either or both buttons being on:

```
always @(A or B) begin
    if (state == NONE_ON) begin
        if(A) begin next_state = A_ON; **do one thing**
          end else if (B) begin next_state = B_ON; **do another**
        end
    end
    else if (state == A_ON) begin
        if (!A) begin next_state = NONE_ON; 
          end else if (B) begin next_state = AB_ON; **do the B things***
        end
    end
    else if (state == B_ON) begin
        if (!B) begin next_state = NONE_ON; 
          end else if (A) begin next_state = AB_ON; **do the A things***
        end
    end
    else if (state == AB_ON) begin
        if (!A) begin next_state = B_ON;
          end else if (!B) begin next_state = A_ON;
        end
    end 
end
```

In some sense keeping track of state like this is the whole point of a state machine which is what you say you are trying to build, and this is a common motivation to build a state machine in the first place.

However if the state machine you were intending to build is at all complex, then adding further A/B information to the state table could significantly multiply your states and make the overall state machine a good deal more complex and spaghetti-like, since your intended states may end up as additional sub-states of A_ON, and of B_ON, and also of AB_ON.

On the other hand, depending on what you were trying to do, given that you were trying to build a state machine based on A or B being pressed it seems very likely that at least some of this information might already be implied (for example that at least *some* button was pressed) in the states you originally had in mind, so it might not change the complexity all that much.

(Note that if you're concerned about handling the possibility of both buttons being pressed or released simultaneously that would also make this implementation more complicated as well.)